# How/Can I exclude inherited foreign libs from ClojureScript compiler output?

Tags: leiningen, clojurescript, reagent, cljsbuild

I am using `reagent 0.5.0` which depends on `cljsjs/react`. The latter comes with the following `deps.cljs`

```
{:foreign-libs [{
 :file "cljsjs/development/react.inc.js",
 :file-min "cljsjs/production/react.min.inc.js",
 :provides ["cljsjs.react"]}],
 :externs ["cljsjs/common/react.ext.js"]}
```

which makes the React's JavaScript end up in the compiler output.

I would like to prevent this from happening, because I also want to use React in plain JavaScript pages.

Besides, `reagent/core.cljs` has a `:require [cljsjs.react]` directive (To force the inclusion?) so the dependency cannot simply be omitted.

Is there a way to prevent React from ending up in the compiler output?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use the bundled react.js in your native JS code? I think it exports to `window`, so you should be able to use it that way.

Comment: I would prefer not to have native JS depend on output generated by the ClojureScript compiler. In fact, I would like to have ClojureScript compiled code and native JS depend on a webjars version of React. Still, I might end up doing what you suggest if there is no alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Reagent Readme (https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent):

If you want the version of React with addons, you'd use something like this instead:

```
[reagent "0.5.0" :exclusions [cljsjs/react]]
[cljsjs/react-with-addons "0.12.2-4"]
```

If you want to use your own build of React (or React from a CDN), you have to use :exclusions variant of the dependency, and also provide a file named "cljsjs/react.cljs", containing just (ns cljsjs.react), in your project.

So, just use the :exclusions option in your dependencies, and provide your own cljsjs/react namespace and your good to go. It's up to you at that point to ensure React is loaded before Reagent however.

Comment: Missed the trick to add my own empty `clsjs.react` namespace. Works perfectly. Thanks!